# PHP Date not Inserting with correct format

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Situation:**

Trying to run a query to insert the `userID` and `Date` into MySQL causes the user id to be inserted and the Date to show `0000-00-00`.

**Code:**

```
$stdb->insert('sleep', array('userid'=>$userid,'date'=>date("Y-m-d")), array( '%s','%d' ));
```

**Using:**

Wordpress with custom WPDB Class

I have other queries that work, that are similar (more data being submitted is the difference) and they work with this code functionality.

I have written the `date("Y-m-d")` to logging and it comes out `2016-12-23`

Error Logging does not return errors and the database is setup for Date Formating in a MySQL Column.

What could i be missing?

Comment: When inserting dates to MySQL it requires you to escape the value. Thus you need to put `'` before and after `date("Y-m-d")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, the date("Y-m-d") section was terminating the date after the first - by changing it to date("Ymd") I was able to see the date relay correctly in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting to unix time before sending?  Try changing:

`'date'=>date("Y-m-d"))` to `date()`

Assuming your db is synced with your php date/time you could just use `now()`

Comment: Why not just `time()` then?

Comment: why not indeed, thats a much better answer... Although I guess a better way would be to use mysql to timestamp. As long as both times are synced

Comment: It's irrelevant since he says in the question that the column is a DATE.

Comment: although a timezone would effect the date

Answer (score 0):

For inserting date from php and mysql you can use this code.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$date = date("d-m-y");

$sql = "INSERT INTO disp_time(userId, date) VALUES ('username','$date')";

if($link->query($sql)){
    echo "Query Successfully inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed to insert".$sql."<br>".$link->error;
}
?>
```